# Panasonic GH4 vs. a Canon 1200D for still photography?

Tags: canon, panasonic

I currently have a Canon EOS 1200D and really need to upgrade as I want to start doing more high quality video.

Has anyone had any experience with a Panasonic GH4? I've heard it's really good for video, but I haven't heard much about its still photography capabilities.

Would the GH4 be an improvement on the 1200D in regards to still photography? I know it is definitely multiple steps up in relation to video.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "an improvement" would mean to you?

Comment: @mattdm overall crisper and less noiser photos.

Comment: "Better" in what way? In what shooting conditions? One may be "better" in bright light at ISO 100 and the other "better" at high ISO in dim light. One may be "better" in difficult AF situations of sports/action (because no matter how low noise the sensor is, and out of focus subject is blurry, not crisp), the other may be "better" at taking photos of static subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Panasonic GH4 is very good for photography and produces high quality images for its generation. You can read my [in-depth review of the GH4 here](https://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/gh4/review). While I do cover video, all my reviews are centered around the photographic capabilities of the camera.

Now specifically compared to the Canon EOS 1200D which is from around the same time-frame, you will see some improvements, mostly in terms of dynamic-range where the GH4 can capture one more stop than the 1200D. Low-light performance is about the same, although at high ISO, the larger APS-C sensor of the 1200D delivers a small advantage.

The nice thing though is that the GH4 is much more sophisticated and has tons of features not found on the 1200D. It is faster, has much more efficient controls and a larger 100% coverage viewfinder. A full list of features is shown on the first page of the review linked above.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have to ask yourself before you get into all the technical stuff is, is it usable. How are you going to use it?

The articulating screen, the stereo mic input, and the headphone output are essential for people who are doing run-and-gun videos. Don't get too hung up on the technical details and until you know how you're going to use the camera.

The GH4 has its limitations, but it can record 4K video for hours without overheating.

Comment: The OP was asking about the _photographic_ qualities of the camera, not the video capabilities.